# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to figure out this error for about 3 hours and have found other examples with same title, but didn't find any solution yet..

The website says:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end, in /controllers/carts_controller.rb Line 17

```
respond_to do |format|    ///////  <-- says here the problem
```

The rails server says the problem is:

```
views/carts/show.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

...and here is the whole code:

/controllers/carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @carts = Cart.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.xml { render :xml => @carts }
        end
    end

    def show
        begin
            @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            logger.error "Attempt to access ionvalid cart #{params[:id]}"
            redirect_to store_url, :notice => 'Invalid cart'
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html
                format.xml { render :xml => @cart }
            end
        end
    end
    def new
        @cart = Cart.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.xml { render :xml => @cart }
        end
    end

    def edit
        @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @cart.save
                format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cart }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def update
        @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])
                format.html { redirect_to(@cart, :notice => 'Cart was successfully updated.') }
                format.xml { head :ok }
            else
                format.html { render :action => "edit" }
                format.xml { render :xml => @cart.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @cart = current_cart
        @cart.destroy
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Your cart is currently empty') }
            format.xml { head :ok }
        end
    end
end
```

indented all code

the view:
views/carts/show.html.erb

```
<div class="cart_title">Your Cart</div>
<table>
    <%= render(cart.line_items) %>
    <tr class="total_line">
        <td colspan="2">Total</td>
        <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

---

### **SOLUTION FOUND:**

The problem was on *views/carts/show.html.erb*. Changing **cart** to **@cart** solved the problem.

---

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Man, indentation of your code is really messed up. I bet you have missing or extra `end` in there. And it's a nightmare to detect it visually. Good luck :)

Comment: Tryed to put some ends, tryed with ends alot, but didnt find where..

Comment: Format your code first, then try to find loose ends

Comment: Is it any fast way or the only way - owerwrite it?

Comment: Some editors have a button for reformatting code. I use RubyMine, it has such button

Comment: You have a `before_action :set_cart`.Post your full controller code including `set_cart method` and also at which line did the error show up?

Comment: @mansim: what ruby are you using? Maybe it doesn't support this weird `rescue`/`else` syntax.

Comment: What line does it say the error is on?

Comment: Please show the full error and your `show` view - you might be missing an end in the view

Comment: ruby -v is 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22), rails -v is Rails 4.0.2.

Comment: Where i can find this before_action :set_cart method? It was created i think together with scaffold

Comment: @mansim Copy the entire controller code in the question. `CartsController` class should have a `set_cart` method. Also, `cart_params` method is missing too.

Comment: It is entire. The 2nd is entire. The first is what the error reported where is the problem. there is /// <-says here is the problem

Comment: Can you share the full error log generated in the question. You can get it either from terminal where you are running `rails server` or your log file.

Comment: On website says the problem is at /controllers/carts_controller.rb, line 17 (respond_to do |format|), and on rails server says the problem is views/carts/show.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting &end. The 2nd code is controllers/carts_controller, and the 3rd code is carts/show.html.erb

Comment: In my books seems it says to do so..

Comment: You should be using `@cart` instead of `cart` in your view. I'm not sure if that will fix your issue, but it certainly needs to be fixed.

Comment: One of you should submit an answer and @mansim should accept it so this question doesn't go unanswered, like so many here at SO.

Comment: yes, someone pls submit an answer so i could check it.